# How to solve discarded git protocol over https or ssh issue

Tags: node.js, git, github, protocols

Github Discarded git protocol over https or ssh .

To read more about here -  [Improving Git protocol security on GitHub](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/)

Package won't work using git:// protocol

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Fixes I Did in node js

- Added script  "preinstall": "git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://"
- Added unsafe-perm = true In .npmrc file. (optional if u getting some write permission  issue )

Comment: This seems wildly unsafe.  Every user of your package will have their global configuration changed.  Why wouldn't you just set this for yourself and not try to modify every user of your package, or better yet, just fix the broken packages if you have access to them?